# Blocked requests on Openshift?

Tags: openshift, whitelist, blocked

I've an application hosted on openshift for which I've added a Pinterest button. Unfortunately it doesn't work fully. When trying to use it, I get "Could not fetch the image" from Pinterest.

When I asked the Pinterest support, the answer was that openshift probably blocks requests based on the user agent string or requests from Amazon Web Services.

I haven't found any information about requests being blocked at all. Anyone knows anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using secure images when you create the Pinterest button. It sounds like you're trying to load non-secure images on a secure rhcloud.com subdomain.

Comment: The domain is a secure rhcloud.com subdomain and the url used when creating the button starts with `https`. Is that what you mean with using "secure images"?

Comment: A 404 status code sounds like a potential broken image link? I just created an OpenShift PHP app, uploaded [a copy](https://pinterest-jlucky.rhcloud.com/openshift_pinterest_test.jpg) of the default image Pinterest uses in their [button widget builder](https://business.pinterest.com/en/widget-builder#do_pin_it_button), created a new button widget, and pushed the changes to my app and it seems to be working fine: http://pinterest-jlucky.rhcloud.com/.

Comment: Tried your example, it gives the same result when trying to pin: "Sorry we could not fetch the image.".

Comment: Opened a bug a Red Hat, according to the person looking at it, the button on your page worked fine. I've have tried over 20 times the last 36 hours and it have never worked, strange...

Comment: Send a link over to the page with the button you're trying to use and I'll take a look.

Comment: The page is https://www.mywedlibs.com/. Got a new reply from Pinterest's support, saying they would fix the problem in 2 two weeks (no technical explanation given).

Comment: Weird. The Pin it button is actually working fine for me in Firefox/Chrome/Safari. [The image](https://www.mywedlibs.com/images/pinterest.png) showed up with a broken image icon for a split second then loaded fine.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit strange alright. Btw, thank you very much for your help with this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried using your pinit button on mywedlibs.com and see the error. BTW I see a 400 error and not a 404. Try it again and you might find that it's still failing.

Comment: @user3681243 did you ever resolve this? I am using Openshift and am experiencing the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: @looloobs you can follow the bug he posted on Red Hat Bugzilla https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1164552